# Half integral weight Hecke operators

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, automorphic-forms, half-integral-weight

I would like to find a source giving the exact formula for the product of two Hecke operators $T_{\kappa}(n^2)$ and $T_\kappa(m^2)$ of half integral weight. That is, $\kappa \in \frac 12 \mathbb{Z} - \mathbb{Z}$. I am searching for a formula which is similar to
$$
T_k(m)T_k(n) = \sum_{d|(m,n)} d^{k-1}T_k\left(\frac{mn}{d^2}\right)
$$
in the case of full integral weight $k$.

I suspect the answer to be exactly the same, since double coset decompositions in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})^+$, and in its double cover should correspond to each other in a one-to-one fashion. The only difference being that the half integral Hecke operators are supported only on the squares.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can find the answer [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4326).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted. Although I am a little surprised that the $T(p^{2l})$ term does not appear in the expansion of $T(p^2l)T(p^2)$. I guess what is happening is that the matrices required for $T(p^{2l})$ term are there in the double coset decomposition, but the second components of the representatives act in such a way that makes it vanish on modular forms.

Comment: I am glad I could help.

Comment: @GHfromMO The link is now broken. Any chance of getting the information? Thank you.